# Angular Universal Express prerender using wrong path src/src instead of just src/

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying out the `npm run prerender` command in my Angular 11 project, but I get this error:

```
Generating browser application bundles...Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/xyz/edApp3b/src/src/main.server.ts'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
    at NodeJSFileSystem.NodeJSReadonlyFileSystem.readFile (/home/xyz/edApp3b/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/file_system/src/node_js_file_system.js:98:23)
    at EsmDependencyHost.DependencyHostBase.recursivelyCollectDependencies (/home/xyz/edApp3b/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/dependency_host.js:81:40)
    at EsmDependencyHost.DependencyHostBase.processFile (/home/xyz/edApp3b/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/dependency_host.js:136:22)
    at EsmDependencyHost.DependencyHostBase.collectDependenciesInFiles (/home/xyz/edApp3b/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/dependencies/dependency_host.js:56:26)
    at ProgramBasedEntryPointFinder.getInitialEntryPointPaths (/home/xyz/edApp3b/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/program_based_entry_point_finder.js:49:18)
    at ProgramBasedEntryPointFinder.TracingEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (/home/xyz/edApp3b/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/tracing_entry_point_finder.js:45:41)
    at /home/xyz/edApp3b/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/analyze_entry_points.js:28:41
    at new ClusterMaster (/home/xyz/edApp3b/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:45:30)
```

As you can see in the first line of the error output, it is looking for `main.server.ts` in `src/src/` instead of just `src/` ... why is that?, and how do I fix it?

I just installed express engine with `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`, that's it. So I didn't do any of the configuration myself. I've been looking around in config files but there is no obvious values related to prerender and a path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration is in `tsconfig.server.json`. There you can change the path to the required files (`main.server.ts` and `server.ts` are defaults). You might also need to update the path to `servers.ts`

```
  "files": [
      "main.server.ts",
      "../server.ts"
  ],
```

Comment: It seems that `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` for angular 11 installs a tsconfig.server.json file with incorrect paths in the files section. I corrected the paths exactly as you wrote here, and it worked. Thanks! :-D

Comment: Good to know. I'm stuck with v10.x and had somehow to solve it.